# About Jeditable jquery plugin in the context of Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, backbone.js

Using the [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin,
is possible to create, very easily, a submit and cancel button.
Here's a very simple code example (*)

Now let's suppose in `MyView` (Backbone.View) I would like to trigger the event click on the button submit which is created by Jeditable.
Here's the code regarding the `Backbone.View` (**).

When I trigger the event `"click .submitBtn"` the value of $('.edit_area').text is empty string.
In order to fix this issue I implemented the following code (* **)

Do you have some smart idea to improve the code of (* **)? I don't like callback using `setTimeout`.

---

(*)

```
 $('.edit_area').editable(function(value, settings) {
        return(value);
     }, { 
     type      : 'textarea',
     submit    : '<div class="submitBtn">Ok</div>'
     cancel    : '<div class="submitBtn">Undo</div>'
 });
```

---

(**)

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            "click .edit_area"          : "edit",
            "click .submitBtn"          : "close"
        },
});
```

---

(* **)

```
close: function close () 
{ 
    var that = this;
    console.log($(this.el).find("[data-tid='editable']").text()); // empty string
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log($(that.el).find("[data-tid='editable']").text()); // update string
        that.model.save({
            name: $(that.el).find("[data-tid='editable']").text()
        });
    }, 0);
},
```

Comment: there is a typo switch the order of these two statements to below     `var that = this;
console.log($(that.el).find("[data-tid='editable']").text()); // empty string`

Comment: @Deeptechtons thanks, anyway the problem remains.

Comment: maybe You want to see "Submitting to function instead of URL" section of jEditable. Where you are capable of handling the text typed into textarea

Comment: @Deeptechtons you are right.. because my original code is with a function, I changed my question.

Answer (score 1):

in the initialize function

```
$('.edit_area').editable(this.close, { 
         type    : 'textarea',
         submit  : 'OK',
});
```

Close function definition

```
close:function(value, settings) { 
    this.model.save({
        name: value
    });
  });
```

#### Complete Code

```
var editableview = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        _.bind(this.close, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).find('.edit_area').editable(this.close, {
            type: 'textarea',
            submit: '<div class="submitBtn">Ok</div>'
            cancel: '<div class="submitBtn">Undo</div>'
        });
    },
    close: function (value, settings) {
        this.model.save({
            name: value
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @underscore666 this **WAS** your problem right ? `Do you have some smart idea to improve the code of (* **)? I don't like callback using setTimeout.` i think the code solves that

Comment: @underscore666 you can view the updated code. It saves the model to the server. Set the `URL` for the model and change `context` of close function to `current view`

Comment: Your idea is nice.. but I have one problem, the editable code is loaded as a module in backbone view...so when I run the function close this refers to the dom and not the the backbone.view.

Answer (score 0):

Var That = This is wrong. This is the DOM not the backbone view. You can do:

```
$('.edit_area').editable(this.close, { 
         type    : 'textarea',
         submit  : 'OK',
         submitdata: {view: this},
});
```

"view" in the hash would be the backbone view. It can be accessed in the close function.

```
close:function(value, settings) { 
    settings.submitdata.view.model.save({
        name: value
    });
});
```